# Google maps v3 synchronized drag

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am currently trying to synchronize the movement of two Google Maps on screen when the user drags them.

Currently I am listening to the `center_changed` event. However that is only called once a drag has been completed, thus the second map only moves after the drag and not during.

My current code looks like this

```
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.287373, -1.548609),
      zoom: 12,
      // streetViewControl: false
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      // draggable: false,
      // disableDoubleClickZoom: false
    };
    mapOptions["styles"] = dayStyle;
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);


    backgroundMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("background-map"),
        mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
        // Set backgroundMap to match actual map
        backgroundMap.panTo(map.getCenter());
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
        // Set backgroundMap zoom to be further out than actual map
        backgroundMap.setZoom((map.getZoom()-2 >= 1) ? map.getZoom()-2 : 1);
    });
```

But I really want to create the same effect that http://snazzymaps.com/ has. I've already tried using the `bindTo` method to link the background map to the foreground map. But that also only updates the background map after the drag is complete.

Answer (score 0):

the `drag` event is the one you want, but use it in conjunction with `center_changed`, because panning using the keyboard arrows will not fire the `drag` event.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that my code does work in desktop environments.

However the maps JS API limits it callback rates in mobile environments (I can only assume it's for performance reasons), and thus only calls `center_changed` once per drag. Unlike the on desktop where it is call far more frequently.